# Delete files over network

Tags: file, batch-file, task, scheduler, delete-file

I have two scripts run by the task scheduler.
First batch file makes a file on network shared folder for each computer in network
and it works ok

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /c "copy /y nul \\mysrv\test\%computername%\pcon.txt"
```

Second script must delete that file, but doesn't delete it, how to solve that.
It runs only if I double click on it
Task is run by user SYSTEM in task scheduler

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /c "del /Q \\mysrv\test\%computername%\pcon.txt"
```

Comment: @AlexejMagura Why? For a lot of tasks, CMD is just as simple and useful as PowerShell. Especially things like copying and deleting.

Comment: Are you running those commands from task scheduler, or are you putting them in a batch file, then calling the batch file from task scheduler?

Comment: @unclemeat CMD makes a poor command-line shell; if compatibility with older Windows machines isn't a concern, don't use CMD.  That being said, there's nothing _wrong_ (AFAIK) with using CMD, but there are a lot more reasons why you'd want to use Powershell instead.  It's like using `bash` over `dash/sh` under Linux: it's just something that you should always do _unless_ you have a _specific_ reason not to do so.

Comment: @AlexejMagura  CMD Vs Powershell wars aren't constructive.

Comment: Verify that SYSTEM has the appropriate security rights to delete the file.

Comment: "Task is run by user SYSTEM in task scheduler" There's your likely problem.  I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988690/powershell-script-on-remote-computer-not-running-as-a-scheduled-task/31993235#31993235).  The question is about scheduling a PowerShell script and you're not trying to use administrative shares, but the issue is otherwise identical.